# Google App Engine datastore index created but still got DatastoreNeedIndexException

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have created a Kind called User in Google App Engine datastore, and I am trying to add an index for this kind.

Firstly, I followed https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/indexconfig to create index by adding datastore-indexes.xml inside war/WEB-INF, but it doesn't work, no index is created after I deploy to app engine.

Then I followed https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/indexref, I created a index.yaml and run `gcloud app deploy index.yaml`, this time I can see the index created in GCP console as seen below.

[Index seen in GCP console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKZ87.png)

But I still got an exception as below:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: 
no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: User
  properties:
  - name: area
  - name: coins_balance

The suggested index for this query is:
    <datastore-index kind="User" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="area" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="coins_balance" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
```

I searched google with "index created but still got DatastoreNeedIndexException", but didn't find any helpful information.

Please can someone help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the properties in the index matters.  The screenshot shows an index for 

`- kind: User
  properties:
  - name: coins_balance
  - name: area`

You actually want:

`- kind: User
  properties:
  - name: area
  - name: coins_balance`

So you can either change your query to match your existing index, or you can build the index that the recommended index.

Comment: Thanks, this actually works. But I still don't understand why datastore-indexes.xml doesn't work, now it only works when I run "gcloud app deploy index.yaml" with index configuration put in index.yaml.